# How do you you find a patent lawyer by looking at patents?

Tags: provisional-application, lawyers

I am looking for a patent lawyer who understands certain subject matter.  in reviewing existing patents i can see the subject mater that is related.  How can i find out who the lawyer was?

Answer (score 1):

Look on the first page of the patent for "Attorney, Agent or Firm".